Supplying 12.5 V @ 50 mA at low cost
Supplying stable 12.5v for programming, using a circuit template and the MC34063A:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MC34063A_D-2315484.pdf
This is my first time designing a boost regulator, and I'd like a second set of eyes to tell me if I'm understanding the formulae correctly. I've listed a couple of questions below my work.
Using the step-up regulator template in the datasheet, I've found values for all of the components necessary to supply 12.5v @ 50mA with a Vin of 5.0v:
Component Values
Vin: 5v
Vin(min): 3.75v
Vout: 12.5v
Iout(max): 50mA
F: 50KHz
Vsat: 1v
Rsc (current sense resistor)= 0.66Ω
R3 (driver resistor) = 180Ω
R2 = 2.4kΩ
R1 = 240Ω
CT (timing cap) = 600pF
CO (output cap) = 17μF
L(min) (inductor 1 minimum inductance) = 90μH
Screenshots from datasheet
12v to 28v example:

Formulae:

My Math
Voltage divider resistance formula:
Vout = 1.25(R2/R1)

12.5v = 1.25(R2/R1)
10 = R2/R1
10 = 2.4kΩ/240Ω

R2 = 2.4kΩ
R1 = 240Ω

ton/toff formula:
ton/toff = (vout + vf - vin(min))/(vin(min) - vsat)
ton/toff = 3.5454545454545454545454545454545 = (12.5v + 1v - 3.75v)/(3.75v - 1v)

ton/toff = 3.5

(ton + toff) formula:
(ton + toff) = 1/f

(ton + toff) = 1/50KHz
(ton + toff) = 0.00002s

toff formula:
toff = (ton + toff)/[(ton/toff)+1]

toff = (1/f)/(3.5 + 1)
toff = 0.00002s/4.5
toff = 0.0000044s

ton formula:
(ton + toff) - toff

0.00002s - 0.0000044s
ton = 0.0000156s

Peak switch current formula:
Ipk(switch) = 2Iout(max)*(ton/toff + 1)

Ipk(switch) = 2(50mA)(3.5 + 1)
Ipk(switch) = 100mA(4.5)

Ipk(switch) = 450mA

Current Sense Resistor formula:
Rsc = 0.3/Ipk(switch)

Rsc = 0.3/450mA

Rsc = 0.66Ω

Timing Capacitor formula:
CT = 4.0x10^-5(ton)

CT = 4.0x10^-5(0.0000156s)
CT = 0.000 000 000 600F

CT = 600pF

Output Capacitor formula:
CO = 9(Iout*ton/Vripple(pp))

CO = 9((50mA*0.000015s)/40 mVpp)
CO = 9(0.00000075/.04Vpp)
CO = 9(0.00001875)
CO = 0.000 16875
CO = 170μF

Inductor minimum inductance formula:
L(min) = ([vin(min) - vsat]/Ipk(switch))ton(max)

L(min) = ([3.75v - 1v]/.45A)ton(max)
L(min) = (2.75v/.45A)ton(max)
L(min) = (6.1)0.000015s
L(min) = 0.000 09
L(min) = 90μH

About ton(max) (I assume the maximum amount of time the circuit will be accumulating before turning off again) -- the datasheet doesn't mention a formula for finding this value. I merely specified the value of ton in stead.
I also noticed that the datasheet doesn't mention or specify a formula for the resistance value of the 1st inductor. Am I safe to use a formula outside of the datasheet for finding its proper resistance value?

The most proper resistance value for the inductor in a boost converter, or indeed most any type of dc-dc converter, is zero. Of course, this is unattainable without wasting far more money and energy than it's worth in superconducting wire, so you just get the smallest resistance you can find while remaining within cost and size restrictions. Check the power ranges from inductor manufacturers like Coilcraft, Würth, and Abracon.


About ton(max) (I assume the maximum amount of time the circuit will be accumulating before turning off again) -- the datasheet doesn't mention a formula for finding this value. I merely specified the value of ton in stead.

What you have calculated with \$t_{on}\$ is fine since that aligns with your switching frequency of 50kHz.

I also noticed that the datasheet doesn't mention or specify a formula for the resistance value of the 1st inductor. Am I safe to use a formula outside of the datasheet for finding its proper resistance value?

This won't be found in that particular datasheet since that is something you'll find in the datasheet for the inductor itself. Typically a rule of thumb is finding something with small DCR. You can probably "trust" that ON Semi has provided a good inductor for the sake of this evaluation board.
Very good job on the calculations by the way. This is a useful exercise if you get involved with power electronics after your education.
